# Avoid feedback on acoustic guitar when plugged on stage

Tags: acoustic-guitar, audio-feedback

I'm using an acoustic guitar with built-in pickup (on-board pickup - undersaddle pickup specifically), which have a soundhole of course. If I'm playing on-stage, the guitar wil give some feedback sound, which it's kinda annoys me.

How to avoid that? I don't want to use any soundhole cover or move far a (bit, perhaps) from the amplifier or even reducing the volume.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your objection to using a soundhole cover.  Soundhole covers only affect your tone if you're playing acoustically or into an external mic.  A soundhole cover won't affect the output from an undersaddle pickup at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feedback is a resonance between the speakers / monitors and your strings / pickup - the frequency and volume is very position dependent, and the resonance of your guitar will make some frequencies much more prevalent than others, so the usual solutions include:

- using an EQ, cut the specific frequency that is giving you trouble
- move away from the speakers
- move the speakers themselves, or angle them away from you

You can also damp the strings if the problem is string resonance, or add a cloth or damping material into your guitar if it is body resonance.